# C# new string[2] vs new string[]

Tags: c#, string, allocation

Is there a difference between the following In terms of performance?

```
private static readonly string[][]  a = { new string[] {"a", "b", "c"}};
private static readonly string[][]  a = { new string[3] {"a", "b", "c"}};
```

Assuming I can write the 2 options (I know the values that will be in the array beforehand) which is better / more correct?

Comment: No, there isn't.

Comment: It will generate exactly the same IL code, as will this: `private static readonly string[][] a = { new [] { "a", "b", "c" } };`

Comment: I would go first option, not because of being better or more correct, which it is not, but because it is easier to later not mess with. You add items later and forget changing that `3`...  `new string[3] {"a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"}`

Comment: No difference whatsoever - The decompiled IL generated by both lines results in `string[][] b = new string[1][]
 {
  new string[3]
  {
   "a",
   "b",
   "c"
  }
 };`

Comment: [Which is faster](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/).

Comment: I'd strongly prefer the first one. It is less error prone. In the case the array changes, if you use the second version the code would have to be modified in two places

Comment: This is pretty much the definition of [premature optimisation](https://stackify.com/premature-optimization-evil/). Even it this was likely to be "faster" what makes you think that, that is important?

Comment: It's not an intepreted language where it will count the number of item before initialising the array. All those happends at compilation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both generates the same IL codes, so same performance, and both are correct.

The only advantage of the second option is when you need to restric the number of elements, it will give you a compile error if you put more or less elements.

```
// error
private static readonly string[][] a = { new string[3] {"a", "b"}};
```